# Не работают стили на старых версиях

Tags: android

Объявляю стиль res/values/styles.xml

```
  <style name="EditTextTheme" >
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greyBack</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Указываю данный стиль в EditText:

```
<com.group.improve.improvegrouptestproject.ImpGroupEditText
            android:hint="@string/si_username_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
            android:id="@+id/si_et_username"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rigth_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin" />
```

Данный код срабатывает на новых версиях Android, на старых(например 4.2.2 Moto X) стили не работают. Как заставить это работать и на старых версиях?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так ещё прописать: `style="@style/EditTextTheme"`

Comment: Да, заработало спасибо. Напишите это как ответ, я помечу ваше решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работало на старых версиях, надо прописать стиль ещё и в качестве значения атрибута `style`:

```
style="@style/EditTextTheme"
```